# Unable to parse delimiter in Peg.js parser

Tags: peg, pegjs

I am learning how to write a parser using peg.js and encountered a unique problem. I am using `;` as a delimiter to categorize the string in key value pair.

*Example*: if the string to be parsed is `name=prabesh;city=Bangalore`. My parser currently takes `name` as a key and `prabesh` as a value and `city` as key and `bangalore` as value.

The question is what if the delimiter is a part of the string?

For example: `city=bangalore;address=#12/1;santacruz`

How can you parse it?

*Approach*: search for consecutive `;`'s
i.e from first `=` search for consecutive `;` and then consider the text between `=` and last `;` as a value.

The problem with this approach is that if the value itself has a `=` then the parser would fail to parse it correctly.

For example, this fails: `token=crbz23;4=134;`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

With PEG grammars, you need to be specific about what you don't want to match. In your example, you would want a lookahead to *not* match a new key if you encounter a semicolon. A common PEG idiom for solving this problem looks like this: `(!(id) .)+`. Here's an example using your input:

```
start =
    exp+

exp =
    key '=' val ';'?

key =
    $([a-z]+)

val =
    $((!(';' key '=') .)+)
```

Input:

```
city=bangalore;address=#12/1;santacruz
```

Output:

```
[
   [
      "city",
      "=",
      "bangalore",
      ";"
   ],
   [
      "address",
      "=",
      "#12/1;santacruz",
      null
   ]
]
```